# Trigger event on Live Agent accept chat

Tags: liveagent, servicecloud

I want to auto-assign a case to a user if the user accepts a live agent chat that has the case details attached to it in the pre-chat form, and the case isn't already assigned to an individual. I'm having trouble identifying a trigger/event that I can tap into to do this. Has anyone else done something similar? Am I looking in the wrong place?